# Onclick Random Redirect from List

Tags: javascript, html, random, onclick

I'm trying to create a button on my website that opens a random page from a list in a new tab.

I think I'm pretty close, but when a new tab opens it is an "about:blank" page.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

What I've tried is below

```
`<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Redirect From List</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
  <body>
      <div style="text-align:center;padding:15px;">
     
    <button style="text-align:center;" onclick="window.open()" type="button" name="" id="" class="btn btn-primary" btn-lg btn-block target="_blank">Random Website</button>    
    </div>
    <script>
        var links = [
        "http://www.google.com",
        "http://www.yahoo.com",
        "http://www.bing.com",
        "http://www.duckduckgo.com"
    ]

    function openLink() {
        var i = parseInt(Math.random() * links.length);
            location.href = links[i];
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>`
```

I'm using google, yahoo, bing, duckduckgo as placeholder websites, and I want it so that when I click the button, a random webpage from my Var Links list will open, so that I can update the URL's as I add content.

However, right now, a new tab opens, but it doesn't open any of the webpages from the list. Is there an error that I'm missing?

Comment: `openLink` is never called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is working:

```
<div style="text-align:center;padding:15px;">
  <button style="text-align:center;" onclick="openLink()" type="button" name="" id="">Random Website</button>
</div>
<script>
var links = [
  "http://www.google.com",
  "http://www.yahoo.com",
  "http://www.bing.com",
  "http://www.duckduckgo.com"
];
function openLink() {
  var i = parseInt(Math.random() * links.length);
  window.open(links[i], '_blank');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

It looks like the below was the problem. and the function wasn't referencing the list of links.

 'function openLink() {
        var i = parseInt(Math.random() * links.length);
            location.href = links[i];'

Answer (score 1):

You're just opening a new blank window and then reloading the current window with another url!

But if you give the new window a variable name you'll be able to reference it...

```
var W = window.open();
```

And then point to the new window before changing the url thus...

```
W.location.href = links[i];
```

Comment: Oh my gosh! I feel like I'm so close but still new, so unsure where exactly I'm going wrong. I tried this, and I'm still getting the same result.

  <button style="text-align:center;" onclick="var W = window.open()" type="button" name="" id="" class="btn btn-primary" btn-lg btn-block target="_blank">Random Website</button>    
    </div>
    <script>
        var links = [
        "http://google.com",
        "http://yahoo.com",
    ]

    function window.open() {
        var i = parseInt(Math.random() * links.length);
            W.location.href = links[i];

Comment: Err no... look just change to what Jacob has offered you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign openLink to your button.
right here
onclick="openLink()"

button style="text-align:center;" onclick="openLink()" type="button" name="" id="" class="btn btn-primary" btn-lg btn-block target="_blank">Random Website</button

Comment: Thanks, I switched it to this, 
<button style="text-align:center;" onclick="openLink()" type="button" name="" id="" class="btn btn-primary" btn-lg btn-block target="_blank">Random Website</button>

But when now it doesn't even open a new tab. Nothing on the website changes.